# how make django sleep

Tags: python, django, django-channels, channel

I have a project in which one client register a request and some other clients must answer if they want to work with him or not in real time the problem is that how can i sleep the consumer of him to wait until one of them accepted
if i use time.sleep() the whole project will sleep

```
class ConsulationConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connet(self):
        pass 

    def diconnect(self,code_close):
        pass 

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        consultation = text_data_json['message']
        consulator=ConsultationOrder.objects.get(id=consultation).lawyer

        if(consulator==None):
            consulator=0        
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': consulator
        }))
```

Comment: Why not use an ```AsyncWebsocketConsumer```?

Comment: You're looking at some sort of notification mechanism instead of sleep. You can use a queue like RabbitMQ and have the client publish a message on the queue if it wants to work or not. Not adding this as an answer as it is not a direct answer to the question, but a better approach to the problem

Comment: Frankly, I don't think your approach is the best one. Why would you need to use sleep to wait for someone to accept. You can just leave the connection open and then send a message to the user through the websocket once someone has accepted. The following docs might help https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers
You could send a message to the user who is waiting for an answer using `channel_layer.send` and passing channel name of that user

Comment: The problem is that i want to ask people by turns and everyone only has 1 min to accept or ignore after one min he can not accept and the next one must choice this is why i wanted to use the  sleep to change the  condidate .

Comment: with a lot of thanks to @shoaib30 for his great guide i used celery to solve problem and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I used Celery to solve the problem
I used apply_async and countdown to solve the problem this way

I created a celery task and inside a for loop I used apply_async with countdown

```
for idx,lawyer in enumerate(lawyers):
    if(consultation.lawyer):
        break      
    change_offered_lawyer.apply_async((id,lawyer.id),countdown=idx*60)
```

this way each time based on the count of idx the view will wait and then will call the task